# Battery lifetime as normal distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

I want to model battery lifetime, which decrements continuously at every epoch (i.e., work-cycle) in the following way. So it takes values such as 100, 99.7, 99.3, 99.2, ... 0 (a continuous random variable). How can I convert it into Gaussian distribution? Also, how to normalize the resultant Gaussian distribution with an arbitrary mean and standard deviation?

My apologies if question is not correct as I am new to the probabilistic modeling.

Comment: An issue with a Gaussian distribution is that it gives a non-negative probability of negative values.

Comment: @Henry Can you please further explain your comment with a simple example, as I mentioned in the question that I am new in the "beautiful world" of probabilistic modeling.

Comment: A Gaussian distribution has positive probability density on the whole Real Number Line: the tails of the bell curve stretch between $-\infty$ and $+\infty$. If the mean is positive and the standard deviation is much smaller than the mean then the probability of negative values is very small but still positive.  If you intend to use it for modelling, you need to consider whether this matters.

Comment: @Henry could you please come up with some numbers for being specific rather than generic? By the way, how can I get negative values in battery depletion scenario as the values are only bounded in the closed interval [100, 0]?

Comment: For example, suppose $X$ has mean $50$ and standard deviation $20$, and a Gaussian distribution, then $P(X \lt 0) \approx 0.006$.  In fact if lifetimes tend to decline with each cycle, then the mean is not stationary over time, so you need a more complicated model such as @Daniel McLaury's suggestion of looking at differences; if so, you might feel that the difference being slightly negative is not impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to model the battery depletion per unit time as Gaussian.  So if the battery charge measured each minute is

100, 99.7, 99.3, 99.2, ...

then I'd take the differences between successive values

0.3, 0.4, 0.1, ...

and fit something to that.  Now it's probably better to graph the data first and decide if a Gaussian model appears to be valid, but let's say you've done that.

A Gaussian distribution is determined completely by its mean and variance, and the usual ways of fitting the model generally reduce to calculating your sample mean and variance and taking the Gaussian distribution with those parameters.  If you normalize this, you'll get the mean-0 variance-1 Gaussian no matter what your input data was.

Comment: Yes, your guess is right! Could you please further elaborate upon "Now it's probably better to graph the data first and decide if a Gaussian model appears to be valid," What do you think, which distribution would be more valid considering above behavior of battery depletion rate (and why)?

Comment: Well, if you graph the data, and it doesn't look Gaussian, and you fit a Gaussian model to it anyway, that's probably not a great idea.  I don't have a good intuition for the fundamentals here, but if, say, your data includes some time when the laptop is asleep and some when it's writing a bunch of stuff to disk then you'll probably have a bimodal distribution of battery consumption, to which fitting a Gaussian would be silly.

Comment: hmm.. that is "intuitive" enough example. Thanks!